# eslint no-useless-return in Promise

Tags: javascript, eslint

I just realised that eslint's no-useless-returns is yelling at me for writing the following...

```
const success = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        reject();
        return; // <----
      }, 5000);
      pubs.on('ok', () => {
        console.log('okey!');
        clearTimeout(timer);
        resolve(true);
      });
    });
```

Now I understand what the rule is supposed to tell me, however afaik code execution would continue even after the promise rejected, right? So why is this considered an useless return?

Comment: Because it's the last line of the function anyway?!

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `return` is not related callback function of the Promise:

```
(resolve, reject) => {
   // ... 
}
```

It belongs belongs to the arrow function, passed to the `setTimeout`

```
() => {
  reject();
  return;
}
```

and for that reason, only exits that function, and being the last statement in that function and not returning anything it is useless.

Even if `setTimeout` would do something with the value returned from that function, it would still be useless because `return;` is the only return statement, returns `undefined` and a function without a `return` would also return `undefined`.